# How do I hide the display value of a column in a datawindow when the column value is zero

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

The question says it all. To clarify: I am not trying to hide the whole column, I just want to hide the display value when it is being equal to zero.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One interpretation of what you're saying is to make the format mask end in a pound sign, like `#,###`. Another interpretation would be to make a `Visible` expression dependent on the value of the column, like (untested) `if (*colname*=0, '0', '1')`. I'm guessing you're after the former.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth knowing that you can specify four different format masks for one datawindow column.  You simply create up to four masks separated by semicolon.

**Sample Format Mask:** 
$#,##0.00;RED;#;'null'

1. Positive Values use $#,##0.00
2. Negative Values use RED
3. Zero Value use #
4. Null Value uses 'null'

**Produces These Result:**

123.01 --> $123.01

-123.01 --> ($123.01) in red text

0 -->

null --> null